# Change LED dimmed signal to full power when turned on?

Tags: transistors, led, circuit-design, dimmer, dimming

Here's the scenario...

EDIT: Everyone seems to so far be missing the part about **ELIMINATING** the dimming, first and foremost.

I have a 12v circuit that is powering an LED array.  On some event, the array is dimmed by some sort of modulation (current?) to dim LEDs where 12v is still measured from the source.  ***Call this source "A".***

I have a separate 12v source that is constant, ***call that source "B".***

Something like this:

[image]

How can I use this constant ***source B*** to **ELIMINATE** the dimmed signal from ***source A*** so that the LED array is at full brightness/voltage but **ONLY** when there is some voltage/signal coming from ***source A***. The issue with the 12v ***source B*** is that it does not shut off, so on/off needs to be controlled if there is some sort of voltage at ***source A***.

Of course you can't send the 12v from Source B right to the LED array all the time because when the power turns off from Source A, it must not come from source B either.

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated!  I'm only basic hobbyist circuit designer!

Comment: I'm not understanding what behavior you want to see here.  You want the LEDs to be powered from source A...unless source A is on?

Comment: Welcome! Your power supply is in series with your load. It should be in parallel. I don’t understand either what function you want. Can you draw a truth table?

Comment: Any 3 position SPDT switch can do that. In case the PSs have separate grounds use DPDT.

Comment: Please re-read again.  It should be very clear.  And any manual switches of course will not work.  And I only put the constant source B in the diagram as a reminder that it is there.

Comment: Use a relay controlled by source A to open/close the circuit from source B. Power everything from B.

Comment: Either it's as simple as @user1850479 says or you'll need to explain it with a truth table (which after schematics is the language of EE's around the world).